# Parse command line args as numbers in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I am writing a simple script using Racket and I want to pass in three values from the command line. Two floats and an integer.

My initial thought was to try this:

```
(define args (current-command-line-arguments))
(define c (string->number(car args)))
```

but that did not work as expected. I received this error:

```
car: contract violation
  expected: pair?
  given: '#("3" "2")
```

I'm new to Racket, but I think the the `#` means procedure rather than list. I just need a list of the arguments.

I found some [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Command-Line_Parsing.html) on parsing command line args from Racket, but it seems to be designed to parse for switches/options rather than just values.

Can anyone offer any advice? thanks.

Comment: The `command-line` macro that you linked to does let you specify the number of arguments with `#:args` (saves you some code to check that). You're correct that you still have to check/parse the individual arguments yourself though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result of current-command-line-arguments is a vector. Use [`vector-ref`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/vectors.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._vector-ref%29%29) instead of `car`.

```
(define c (string->number(vector-ref args 0)))
```